# How do I turn a piecewise polynomial into a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, polynomials, piecewise

I have been fitting some data generated in the lab. The best fit is by piecewise polynomial
[image: fit generated from lab data]

I would now need to turn this into a function that I can then plug in a model (where I repeat this function with different time delays and then sum them up). What is the best way to do this? If I generate a fit wth the FIT function, I am then unable to use that object as a normal function. Any advice?

Comment: I would suggest trying to find a functional form that fits your data (a skewed exponential might work). That way you will only need a few coefficients to describe your data. A piecewise polynomials will end up requiring the coefficient for each piece so may not be more concise than the data.

Comment: @EdSmith great thanks!